# How to decode() with a subset of 'ascii'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, decode

I get bytecode data (`b'something'`) which I `try:` to `.decode('ascii')` to check if this is ASCII text. The problem is that

```
In [11]: b'\x00\x0c\x00'.decode('ascii')
Out[11]: u'\x00\x0c\x00'
```

so what is recognized as "text" is not really what I want (which are `32` to `126` ASCII codes). Is there a way to use a subset of `'ascii'` for the decoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python 2:

```
def test_if_ascii(text):
    if isinstance(test, unicode):
        raise TypeError('hey man, dont feed me unicode plz')
    return all(32 <= ord(c) <= 126 for c in text)
```

in python 3 almost the same, just unicode is call 'str', and bytes are called 'bytes'

```
def test_if_ascii(text):
    if isinstance(test, str):
        raise TypeError('hey man, dont feed me unicode plz')
    return all(32 <= ord(c) <= 126 for c in text)
```

Comment: Thank you - I forgot to mention that this is Python3 (I will update the question)

Comment: no problem, added it too

Comment: This is a good idea, I will also use string.printable for the check, thanks (need to wait some minutes before accepting)